# EA's package documentation HTML report: Non-conform hyperlinks to external websites in diagrams

Tags: enterprise-architect

When generating an HTML report from an EA package, hyperlinks get exported in such a way that they don't work when displayed in Internet Explorer or in Firefox. This is because the exported HTML hyperlink isn't correct. Let's assume that I add a hyperlink element to a diagram pointing to "http://www.google.de" (hyperlink type: Web Site) it'll generate the following HTML code:
`<area shape="rect" coords="73,10,223,30" href="$inet://http://www.google.de">`.

Firefox resolves this to `file:///C:/temp/test/html/EARoot/$inet://http://www.google.de`, which leads to no action. Internet Explorer displays an error page on clicking this. Double-clicking the hyperlink in EA itself works, though.

The question is: Is this a known bug from the HTML reporter or am I missing a setting somewhere?

I'm using EA 7.5.845. I hope it's not a known bug from this version as we don't plan to upgrade to any more recent version so far.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a website link is pretty straightforward. Just make sure you have the correct link type selected from the dropdown.

I created a test file according to your proposed setup in EA 10 on a clean Win7 VM. It still produces an area tag within a frameset but the link works fine in both the current stable Firefox as well as the Internet Explorer in the version preinstalled with Win7.

You may want to try that out for yourself, there is a free 30 days trial available from Sparx (see link below).

There were several bugfixes regarding hyperlinks as can be seen here: http://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/history.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think that the build number would play a role though I mentioned it: According to [http://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/7.5/history.html] the issue was fixed with build 7.5.847: "Diagram hyperlinks to web pages in HTML reports will now display the target page when clicked.". I'll revert to our tooling team and check if we can upgrade to the latest 7.5 build - this shouldn't cost!